# How to add library to an Intellij IDEA sbt Scala Android project?

Tags: sbt, android-library, library-project, sbt-idea

When I'm trying to compile my sbt project in console I get the following error:

> compile
>   [info] Wrote D:\androidProjects\myfootball\target\scala-2.9.1\src_managed\main\scala\my\android\myfootball\TR.scala
>   [info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 1 Java source to D:\androidProjects\myfootball\target\scala-2.9.1\classes...
>   [error] D:\androidProjects\myfootball\target\scala-2.9.1\src_managed\main\scala\my\android\myfootball\TR.scala:9: **type MapView is not a member of package ru.yandex.yandexmapkit**
>   
> [error]   **val map = TypedResourceru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView**
>   [error]                                                  ^
>   [error] one error found
>   [error] {file:/D:/androidProjects/myfootball/}MyFootball/compile:compile: Compilation failed
>   [error] Total time: 2 s, completed 02.10.2012 21:36:23

I've already added library with MapView in *Project Module Settings* -> *Libraries* and ctrl+click work fine on MapView component. 
 Also I'd tried to do this by adding depend in my build.sbt file

```
  libraryDependencies += "ru.yandex" % "yandexmapkit" % "1.0"
```

and depend successfully downloaded when I update sbt in console...but all in vain....
 .. I failed when trying to compile my project. Does anybody know another way for adding library?